# How to delete some columns in a file based on information in a second file?

Tags: text-processing

I have two files that look like this:

```
file1:

1 235 283 567 1001 1002 1009
1 1 2 1 2 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 2 2
1 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

and

```
file2: 
1 567 1002 1009
```

I want to join these files vertically i.e. the output should contain only those columns of `file1` where the values on the first row are common with the values from `file2`:

output:

```
1 567 1002 1009
1 1 0 1
0 0 2 2
1 2 2 2
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '
NR==FNR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){values[$i]};next}
FNR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i in values){nf[i]}}}
{sp=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if (i in nf){printf("%s%s",sp,$i);sp=" "}}}{print ""}
' file2 file1
```

This reads `file2` first, saves each value into an array `values` then processes `file1` - on 1st line it checks which fields are common and saves those field numbers into another array `nf` which is then used as reference to selectively print the corresponding columns.

Answer (score 3):

If do the task by onliner:

```
cut -d' ' -f $(
    echo $(
        head -1 file1 | tr ' ' '\n' |
        grep -nxf <(tr ' ' '\n' <file2) |
        cut -d: -f1
        ) |
    tr ' ' ','
) file1
```

Or with [Thor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/17666/thor)'s comment

```
cut -d' ' -f $(
    head -1 file1 | tr ' ' '\n' |
    grep -nxf <(tr ' ' '\n' <file2) |
    cut -d: -f1 | 
    paste -sd ,
) file1
```

Comment: +1 nice. You can avoid the `echo` by piping the column list into `paste -sd ,`.